# Why is Wordpress Jquery broken?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Well I have really strange problem with the wordpress and with Jquery. Since few week ago when we upgraded the hosting, the Wordpress Jquery in the ACP and in some parts of the widgets on the site is broken. I tried disabling plugins it's same. Tried reinstalling and not adding any plugin, still same. Tried downloading and adding new Jquery files still same. The Ajax/Jquery part of ACP is unresponsive, widget area is unmovable and pages usually are white when loaded. Footer is also not loaded. Other scripts work fine on the server. I think there is incompatible PHP extension that could be causing this. Any idea about what could be the problem?

Comment: I've never heard of a PHP extension that conflicts with jQuery. What would happen if you add a custom JavaScript file? You can get jQuery version info from `jQuery().jquery;`. Also any chance that jQuery is conflicting with other JavaScript libraries (like Prototype)? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ to resolve any conflicts.

Comment: I'm using the latest one. Also I don't think it's conflicting with other JS libraries. When I tried running it from localhost it all worked as it should work and as it was working before. Also I tried adding custom JS files. It's same. I don't know what could be causing this since it started when the hosting was upgraded. Other scripts using jQuery work as intended. There is only problem with Wordpress. Jquery appears to be undefined even after the fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox to see what JS are loading or are conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

try loading jquery in the template head tags by using the following command

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

remove all other verbose loading instructions for jquery in the head.

This will load jQuery in NoConflict mode.

In this mode, the $ value is no longer the delegate name instead you must use jQuery  For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(#somefunction) ...
});
```

Becomes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(#somefunction) ...
});
```

Comment: If I add it the page turns to white. Added it in functions.php file and in load-scripts.php.

Comment: i should add that this causes the jquery to load in NoConflict mode so there are ramifications on the way you use jquery. I have eddited the answer.